# Make rejoin favorite chatrooms (optionally) automatic

Tags: feature-request, chat

There's already a button to rejoin favorite chat rooms in the chat UI.

Please can there be an option to make that automatic. I.e. when I join *any* chat room I automatically join all my regular ones without the hassle of an extra click. (Mostly useful for letting myself always be pingable in pinned browser tabs).

Presumably such a preference could be exposed in the prefs chat tab for user profiles, which already contains two options that modify chat behavior on a per user basis.

Comment: This button seems to have disappeared from the UI...? I'm not seeing it anyway.

Comment: Still there on chat.so for me - I think it only works if you're just in one room at the time you see it possibly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure why I didn't do this before, but it's trivial to do in a userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto rejoin favourites
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http*://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var button = $('input#rejoin-favs');
        button.click();
    });
})();
```

Seemed to work first time.